# Find the sum of the first n num

Tags: javascript

I have an array with numbers. Find the sum of the first N elements to the first zero. Task must be completed with 
Example: - summarize the first 3 elements, because next is the element with the number 0.

Comment: "reduce" is not a loop, you cannot `break` out of it.

Comment: Something that might be important to note is that this isn’t a good assignment: `reduce` isn’t a good choice for this task. With that in mind, consider solutions that seem unclean, like introducing a new object to hold both the sum and a flag indicating whether a zero has been encountered – because every solution meeting the `reduce` requirement will be like that.

Comment: how then it is better to solve a task but by means of "reduce"

Comment: Or, if copying parts of the array is allowed, consider creating an array that stops at the 0 and then doing a simple sum on *that* array with `reduce`.

Comment: @Marta: A for loop (where `break` *will* work) is one of the best solutions to this task.

Comment: `let sum = 0; for(const el of arr) if(el === 0) break; else sum += el;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this as follows:

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 3, 0, 16, 35, 1];

let sum = arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf(0)).reduce((sum, v) => sum + v);

console.log(sum);
```

> I first extract the numbers in front of the first zero using [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Then I use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to compute the sum of these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can not break the iteration of `reduce()`. You can use a flag variable based on which you can add value to `sum`.

Try the following way:

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 3, 0, 16, 35, 1];
let flag = true;
let sumNum = arr.reduce((sum, elem) => {
  if (elem == 0) {
    flag = false;
  };
  if(flag) return sum + elem;
  else return sum + 0;
}, 0)
console.log(sumNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize an external variable `stopCounting` to flag if the counting should continue or not.

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 3, 0, 16, 35, 1];
let stopCounting = false;

let sumNum = arr.reduce((sum, elem) => {

  if (elem == 0) {
    stopCounting = true;
  }

  return stopCounting ? sum : sum + elem;
}, 0);

console.log(sumNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate with a short circuit and check the value and add the value if not zero.

This approach does not search for zero in advance and needs only a single loop in the worst case.

```js
var array = [10, 20, 3, 0, 16, 35, 1],
    sum = 0;
    
array.every(v => (sum += v, v));

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const arr = [10, 20, 3, 0, 16, 35, 1];
const zeroIndex = arr.indexOf(0);
const total = arr.slice(0, zeroIndex > 0 ? zeroIndex : arr.length)
   .reduce(sum, n => sum+n, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.